# StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 activities A,B,C,D. I need to start activity 'A'(It Consists of a textview,button) initially and from activity 'A' i need to start activity 'B'(With the help of a button).

Now,From 'B' i need to start 'C' & 'D' activities (Condition: Button1(Activity 'B') is hit then it should start Activity 'C'  ,  Button2(Activity 'B') is hit then it should start Activity 'D' ).

--Activity 'C' consists of a EditText & a Button.
--Activity 'D' consists of a EditText & a Button.

Here when i enter text in Edit text of Activity 'C' & 'D' and hit the Button,the result is such that the entered text should appear in TextView of Activity 'A'.

Iam a Beginner to Android,Ple help me in getting through this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dont forget to accept answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 make a static variable in Activity 'C':

```
public static String text="";
```

then read EditText data into String in OnClick of button :

in your Activity'C' on button click:

```
text=edittext.getText().toString();
 Intent i=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class)
 startActivity(in);
 finish();
```

In Activity 'A'

set this text value in OnResume method:

```
Protected void OnResume()
{
super.OnResume();
textview.setText(Activity'c'.text)
}
```

this may help you.ask any doubts

Comment: Only problem here is you can't really count on Activity C or D being active after you've left. Sure, they remain in memory for a little while, but at some point they will be killed and it could be right away.

Answer (score 0):

So you are wanting to pass data from Activity C, or D back to A at some point? Use an application class (google it) and set a variable from your C or D Activities, then call said variable when you get back to A and display the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using `startActivityForResult() you can do like this :

1. `startActivityForResult()` for activity B.
2. `startActivityForResult()` for activity c.
3. On button hit in activity c finish the activity after setting the data.
4. now you will get call in `onActivityResult()` in activity B. repeat the process of setting data in B and finish the activity.
5. now you will get call in `onActivityResult()` in activity A, you got the data now use it.

same process will be for activity D.